# Unable to connect with mongo db shell

Tags: mongodb, terminal, mongodb-shell

After running `mongod` and `mongo` in terminal

```
$mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("707b65a3-c675-4b03-a386-21c5d589c05f") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.6
```

**and nothing happens!** I am unable to create a new database. Please Help!

In another terminal

```
  $ mongod
2020-06-28T20:52:27.841+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-06-28T20:52:28.502+0530 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=14576 port=27017 dbpath=E:\data\db\ 64-bit host=BTL
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.6
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-06-28T20:52:28.504+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-06-28T20:52:28.512+0530 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - E:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.
2020-06-28T20:52:28.514+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in E:\data\db\ created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2020-06-28T20:52:28.514+0530 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2020-06-28T20:52:28.514+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1491M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
2020-06-28T20:52:28.889+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593357748:888613][14576:140705565789264], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 4
2020-06-28T20:52:29.105+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593357749:104639][14576:140705565789264], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 4
2020-06-28T20:52:29.382+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593357749:381648][14576:140705565789264], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 3/5632 to 4/256
2020-06-28T20:52:29.885+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593357749:884866][14576:140705565789264], txn-recover: Recovering log 3 through 4
2020-06-28T20:52:30.476+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593357750:475971][14576:140705565789264], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 4
2020-06-28T20:52:30.693+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593357750:692960][14576:140705565789264], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
2020-06-28T20:52:33.168+0530 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2020-06-28T20:52:36.667+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
2020-06-28T20:52:37.172+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-06-28T20:52:37.172+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-06-28T20:52:37.172+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-06-28T20:52:37.172+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-06-28T20:52:37.172+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2020-06-28T20:52:37.172+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2020-06-28T20:52:37.173+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2020-06-28T20:52:37.173+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2020-06-28T20:52:37.173+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2020-06-28T20:52:37.173+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2020-06-28T20:52:37.173+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-06-28T20:52:42.495+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-06-28T20:52:44.701+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
2020-06-28T20:52:45.029+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-06-28T20:52:45.348+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-06-28T20:52:47.258+0530 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-06-28T20:52:51.373+0530 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'E:/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2020-06-28T20:52:51.410+0530 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-06-28T20:52:51.411+0530 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
2020-06-28T20:52:51.411+0530 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-06-28T20:52:51.411+0530 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
2020-06-28T20:52:52.042+0530 I  FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
2020-06-28T20:52:52.520+0530 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
```

Comment: `MongoDB server version: 4.2.6` indicates the shell connected to the server.

Comment: It looks like that your mongod has "freeze", because log file don't have indication of your connection and connection don't print "command prompt".  Have you tried to restart your mongod process?

Comment: See this message in your log: "*Detected unclean shutdown - E:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.*" Have a look at [Recover a Standalone after an Unexpected Shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)